# Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\modif_pro.php on line 10

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php

    $consulta = consultar($_GET["ruc"]);

    function consultar($ruc_prov){
      include("Conexion.php");
      $s="SELECT * FROM productos WHERE no='".$ruc_prov."' ";
      $rs= mysqli_query($enlace,$s);
      $filas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
      return [
      $filas["ruc"],
      $filas["direccion"],
      $filas["nombre"]
      ];
    } 
?>
```

Este es mi codigo no se porque me sale ese error supuestamente es porque recibe que mi consulta es falsa pero esta el valor en mi base de datos

Answer (score 1):

ahí te agregue una linea a tu código debería funcionar correctamente.

en el código que has proporcionado le agregue nueva variable $rs
mysqli_query($enlace,$rs) or die (mysqli_error)

generalmente con esa sentencia de código hace que tu consulta se ejecute de forma correcta, si hay un error de mysql te lo arrojara ahí mismo.

```
$consulta = consultar($_GET["ruc"]);
function consultar($ruc_prov){
include("Conexion.php");
$rs="SELECT * FROM productos  WHERE id='".$ruc_prov."' ";
$rs= mysqli_query($enlace,$rs) or die(mysqli_error($enlace));
$filas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
return [ $filas["ruc"],$filas["direccion"],$filas["nombre"] ]; 
}
```

Comment: y si explicas tu código? no solo debe ser el script sino que expliques que corregiste